# Google Content API - find products not related to specific seller

Tags: java, google-shopping, google-content-api

I would like to search in Google Content API similar to what I do with ebay Finding API to retrieve products by keywords not related to specific seller

How can I do it?

In the documentation I see get product call, but it requires merchantId and productId

Answer (score 0):

The Google Content API looks like it's more geared towards sellers and the people brought on to manage their offerings. I poked around in the Java samples they had on there but couldn't find anything related to pulling products based on keywords, all required a merchantid.